# getPackageInfo(packageName, 0) in android returns object with no info

Tags: android, version

especially the versionName and versionCode which i wanted to check. one is null the other is 0.
The package name is correct. i verified, any ideas ?

```
final PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
        final String packageName = getPackageName();
        if (getMyApp().getURL() == URLS.PROD && getMyApp().IS_CHECK_VERSION == 1) {
            try {
                new Thread() {
                    public void run() {
                        HttpURLConnection conn = null;
                        String responseString = null;
                        try {
                            String versionName = "1.0";
                            try {
                                PackageInfo pi = pm.getPackageInfo(packageName, 0);
                                versionName = pi.versionName;
                            } catch (NameNotFoundException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
```

Comment: whether you wanna to check for your app or all the installed apps

Comment: i just want the version from my manifest, from many posts in stackoverflow i can see this is the way to go. however for some reason in my app android refuses to give me the verison number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok, found it.
You guys could not se it since you don't have my manifest...
accidentally the build system changed android:versionName to android.versionName. so no versionName was defined.
Strangely enough even Lint didn't see it.

:-( stupidity and nothing more.